# Hazelcast Repository Still queries the Database

Tags: spring-data, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I am working on a spring boot project. In that, i have an entity called ProductMap which i want to keep in cache. I did that using MapLoader and defining the configuration for the map as below.

```
@Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        return new Config().setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance").addMapConfig(
                new MapConfig().setName("ProductMap")
                        .setMapStoreConfig(
                                new MapStoreConfig().setEnabled(true).setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.EAGER)
                                        .setClassName("com.hazelcast.example.HzTest.config.ProductMapLoader")
                        ));
    }
```

ProductMap entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@KeySpace("ProductMap")
@Table
public class ProductMap implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;

    private String name;

    private Integer category;

    private Integer productType;
}
```

ProductMapLoader:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
public class ProductMapLoader implements MapLoader<Integer, ProductMap>, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ProductMapRepository productMapRepository;

    @Override
    public synchronized ProductMap load(Integer integer) {
        System.out.println("Load::" + integer);
        return productMapRepository.findById(integer).get();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Map<Integer, ProductMap> loadAll(Collection<Integer> collection) {
        Map<Integer, ProductMap> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer key : collection) {
            ProductMap productMap = this.load(key);
            if (productMap != null) {
                result.put(key, productMap);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Iterable<Integer> loadAllKeys() {
        System.out.println("load all keys" + productMapRepository);
        return productMapRepository.findAllProdMapKeys();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        productMapRepository = applicationContext.getBean(ProductMapRepository.class);
    }
}
```

I am loading the cache on startup,

```
@PostConstruct
public void Init() {
       IMap map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("ProductMap");  // this will load the cache 
}
```

In also created a HazelcastRepository,

```
public interface ProductMapKvRepo extends KeyValueRepository<ProductMap, Integer> {

    List<ProductMap> findByProductType(Integer productType);
}
```

In one of my service methods, it calls `productMapKvRepo.findAll()` and `productMapKvRepo.findByProductType(1).` But the repository still queries the database.

```
Hibernate: select productmap0_.id as id1_0_, productmap0_.category as category2_0_, productmap0_.name as name3_0_, productmap0_.product_type as product_4_0_ from product_map productmap0_
Hibernate: select productmap0_.id as id1_0_, productmap0_.category as category2_0_, productmap0_.name as name3_0_, productmap0_.product_type as product_4_0_ from product_map productmap0_ where productmap0_.product_type=?
```

dependencies used:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and what can i do?

Answer (score 3):

Your logs indicate that your Spring Data repository is Hibernate-backed which means your project is misconfigured. Spring Data Hazelcast doesn't use Hibernate to read data from the Hazelcast IMDG cluster.

If the use of Hibernate is intended(most likely), then you should consider using its native second-level cache capabilities with Hazelcast instead of wrapping Spring Data repositories inside a *MapLoader*. You can find the example [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-hibernate-2ndlevel-cache).

However, if you want to apply the *read-through* caching pattern with a *MapLoader*, you'd need to use a `spring-data-hazelcast` artifact to read data from Hazelcast cluster directly.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz. I have added my dependencies in the above question. Can you please help me how to apply read through caching pattern? Do i need to configure Hazelcast?

Comment: @AjaySankaran I think you have way too many dependencies on your classpath which might generate extra confusion.

To implement read-through, you need two things:
1) Hazelcast with a custom MapLoader implementation (I'd suggest doing that without Hibernate because it's a lot of extra complexity)
2) Something to read data from Hazelcast, this could be either via a plain Hazelcast Client or Spring Data

Comment: Do you want to use embedded Hazelcast instance or keep it separate?

Comment: i want to use embedded hazelcast instance. This is a dummy project in which i am replicating another project. In that project i am using hibernate level 2 cache as well as spring data hazelcast also. The idea behind is that hiberanate level 2 cache is useful for entities that have too many mappings(it will look into cache instead of DB while saving). While i am using spring data hazelcast for situations where entities are queries by other columns rather than ID.

Comment: The reason i am using both is that during application load, i am loading some entities into cache. In that loadup, some are managed by hibernate second level cache. But the problem is, if some method like findByProductType or findByCategory is called, hibernate still queries the database instead of cache as it knows only the id.

Comment: If I can see correctly, you're not using Spring Data Hazelcast since you extend `KeyValueRepository` and not `HazelcastRepository`.

But besides this, have you tried enabling Hibernate's query cache? I think this sounds like a proper solution to the problem you described (fetching entities by arbitrary search criterion)

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz for the idea. But the problem is query cache saves with the parameters passed. In future this entity might be used for large set of criteria and then i would have to load every criteria query on startup. Using spring data hazelcast i can directly query cache instead of database.

Comment: Makes sense. Try connecting to IMDG with `HazelcastRepository` - that should be all to make it work. Also, you could drop Spring Data Hazelcast and just access IMDG directly with `HazelcastInstance`

Comment: Even if i use HazelcastRepository, it still queries the database. Here is the git link of the project i am working. https://github.com/Ajaysankaran/Hazelcast-demo.git

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? I'm *very* interested in a sample project that successfully uses both a JPA repository to initialize the cache and a Hazelcast repository to retrieve data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

While I was working with Spring Boot v2.1.3.RELEASE and Spring v5.1.5.RELEASE , spring was  injecting  `SimpleJpaRepository` type  for  both repositories :
`MyStandardRepository` And `MyHazelCastRepository`,  with the presence only of `@EnableHazelcastRepositories`

By adding  also  `@EnableJpaRepositories` to my `HazelcastConfiguration` class :

spring then injected `SimpleKeyValueRepository` bean type into `MyHazelCastRepository` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.repository.hazelcast"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.repository.dao"})

public class HazelcastConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
         return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
    @Bean
    public KeyValueOperations keyValueTemplate() {
        return new KeyValueTemplate(new HazelcastKeyValueAdapter(hazelcastInstance()));
    }
    @Bean
     public HazelcastKeyValueAdapter  hazelcastKeyValueAdapter(HazelcastInstance hzInstance) {
        return new HazelcastKeyValueAdapter(hzInstance);
     }
     
}
```